# Извлечь значение массива с ключами в строке

Tags: php, массивы, динамические-массивы

Существует массив:

```
$array = ['key1'=>['key2'=>'val']];
```

В строке через точку указаны ключи массива:

```
$keys_string = 'key1.key2';
```

Необходимо ***извлечь*** значение массива используя ключи указанные **через точку** в переменной $keys_string.

Comment: У вас явно что то не так с данными если возникает такой вопрос.

Comment: буквально неделю назад задавали аналогичный вопрос, боты что ли ?

Comment: С данными все в порядке) В Laravel в фильтрах используется нечто подобное, когда в строке через точку указывается ключ при проверке входящих данных.

Comment: Rochfort, если пришлете ссылку буду благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$keys = explode('.',$keys_string );
$value=$array;
foreach($keys as $key){
   $value = $value[$key];
}
var_dump($value);
```

Comment: Побежимов Борис, большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать неограниченную 2-мя ключами глубину:

```
$array = ['key1' => ['key2' => ['key3' => 'val']]];

$keys_string = 'key1.key2.key3';

var_dump($array);

function change(&$arr, $key, $value){
  $link = &$arr;

  foreach(explode('.', $key) as $part){
    if(!is_array($link) || !array_key_exists($part, $link))
      throw new Exception('Invalid path: ' . $keys_string);

    $link = &$link[$part];
  }

  $link = $value;
}

change($array, $keys_string, 'newValue');

var_dump($array);
```

https://repl.it/FP5p/0

Comment: две причины 1. перепутали вопрос 2. Ну и у `if` скобки забыли :)

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ! Пожалуйста перенесите его в тему с изменением значения http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/617303/%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5#