# Изменить значение массива с ключами в строке

Tags: php, массивы, динамические-массивы

Существует массив:

```
$array = ['key1'=>['key2'=>'val']];
```

В строке через точку указаны ключи массива:

```
$keys_string = 'key1.key2';
```

Необходимо ***изменить*** значение массива используя ключи указанные через ***точку*** в переменной $keys_string.

Comment: следующий вопрос будет "Удалить значение массива с ключами в строке"? Сколько там еще вопросов в билете?

Comment: @Ипатьев это действительно разные вопросы, поэтому и 2 темы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если только 2 уровня вложенности

```
$keys = explode(".", $keys_string);

$array[$keys[0]][$keys[1]] = 'val'
```

Или если не 2 уровня

```
$keys = explode(".", $keys_string);
foreach($item as $keys) {
   $val = &$array[($item]; 
} 
$val = 'test';
```

ОБНОВЛЕНО

Суть - добраться по ссылке изменить массив

```
$array = ['key1'=>['key2'=>'val']];
        $keys_string = 'key1.key2';

        $keys = explode(".", $keys_string);
        foreach($keys as $key) {
            $val = &$array[$key];
        }
        $val = 'test';

        var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Спасибо, к сожалению уровень, может быть разный.

Comment: @Konstantin тогда 
$val = '';
foreach($item as $keys) {
    $val = $array[($item];
}
$val = 'test';

Comment: суть в том что бы перебирать массив пока не закончится $keys  и тогда  последнее значение и будет результирующее

Comment: допустим у нас $array = ['key1'=>['key2'=>'val']];
$keys = explode(".", $keys_string); // [key1, key2]
первая итерация цикла будет $val = 'key1'=>['key2'=>'val'], а во второй 'key2'=>'val', выходим из цикла и получаем последнее значение

Comment: занесите все рассуждения отредактировав ответ

Comment: @Konstantin Okhotnick, понял, но присвоение значения переменной $val, не изменит значения массива $array['key1']['key2'] или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: @Konstantin обновил - рабочий пример. Суть - добраться по ссылке изменить массив

Comment: @Konstantin "но присвоение значения переменной $val, не изменит значения массива $array['key1']['key2']" не изменит если не обращаться по ссылке.   $val = &$array[$key]; а тут идёт обращение по ссылке

Comment: Спасибо, проверил - присваивает значение, но не туда... попробую разобраться почему.