# Как составить запрос для обращения к массиву из элементов другого массива?

Tags: php

У меня есть массив вида `$arr1[$val1, $val2, $val3]`. Простой массив. Нужно из этого массива составить запрос ко второму массиву $arr2, который будет вот такого вида `$arr2[$val1][$val2][$val3]`. Значения $val1, $val2 и $val3 берутся из первого массива. Каким образом можно составить из всех значений массива $arr1
конструкцию вида `$arr2[$val1][$val2][$val3]`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9635968/6104996  - почти так, только тут используется строка со значенифми, разделёнными  точкой

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/617309/191482  на русском

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии. Да, это решение. На английском еще нашел очень подробное решение, если кому-то вдруг понадобится, вот [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929875/how-to-access-and-manipulate-multi-dimensional-array-by-key-names-path)